# RestSharp set ConnectionLeaseTimeout

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have multiple backend servers that are load-balanced via one IP address. My frontend makes http calls to these servers using RestSharp.

I want to set the ConnectionLeaseTimeout as currently idle time is so rare that my connections never close and are sticking to one server. We use RestSharp, is there a way of doing this?

I've tried setting it globally via the ServicePointManager for the URI but a short time later ConnectionLeaseTimeout goes back to -1.

Comment: How long between requests? It could be that the `MaxServicePointIdleTime` is elapsing and resetting the connection lease timeout. You can try setting the `MaxServicePointIdleTime` to infinite.

Comment: We are constantly making requests so I don't think we ever reach the idle time which is why the connections never seem to close.

Comment: Maybe we are hitting this, I didn't realise that service points get recycled. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: May be this can help? http://byterot.blogspot.no/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html